# Example of function in L2 but not in H1

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces, normed-spaces

I am having difficulty finding a function that is an element of $ L^2(\mathbb{R}) $ but is not an element of $ H^1(\mathbb{R}) $ on the whole real line. Can anyone think of an example?

Comment: What is $H^1(\mathbb R)$?

Answer (score 6):

Hint: Every function in $H^1(\mathbb R)$ is continuous.

Comment: Touché. What if the function is also in $C^1$?

Comment: Which function?

Answer (score 1):

The $L^2$ function basically could be anything. All typical examples of functions you met so far are $L^2$ functions.

However, $H^1$ is something special. Try to recall the definition of $H^1$, it contains something about "derivative" right? So, an question for you. Take function $f(x)=1$ if $x\in (0,1)$ but $f(x)=0$ otherwise. Is it a differentiable function? is it a $L^2$ function?

Comment: Thank for your response. The problem is simple on a finite interval. I'm having problems finding a function that is in $L^2$ but not in $H^1$ on the whole real line $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Cocomos the function I suggest is defined on the whole real line...

Comment: Oops, I misread. Then you and grew provided the same answer. Can you find a function that must also be differentiable and satisfy $L^2$ but not $H^1$?

Comment: @Cocomos try function $f(x)=x^{-a}$ with different value of $a>0$. For example, take $a=1/2$. You may need to multiply with a cut off function to cut off the tail of $f(x)$